# *** glibc detected *** {binary pathway}: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000639310 ***

Tags: c++, c, glibc

I know a lot of people met this problem and I have gone through a lot of them. But I still can't solve my problem. Here is it:

My code is c++ code. But I need to call a shared library made by c (ODE solver) for my problem.

```
int Reaction::cvodedensewrapper()
```

This is where the functions of ODE solver are called. My class is Reaction and cvodedenseWrapper() is a class function. I define a struct for data transfer from c++ to c as:

```
 typedef struct {
  unsigned int exp_ID, nExp,nRec, nComp;
  realtype *Ts;
  realtype *dTs;
  realtype *ts;
  realtype *vkp;
  realtype Tr;
  } User;
  typedef User *UserData;
```

Here realtype is a name for double type. I define a UserData type variable in my code,  allocate memory and initialize it as:

```
User data;
UserData udata=& data;
udata->Ts=new realtype[numExp];
udata->dTs=new realtype[numExp];
udata->ts=new realtype[numExp];
udata->vkp=new realtype[2*numRec];
udata->nExp=numExp;
udata->nRec=numRec;
udata->nComp=numComp;
udata->Tr=Tref;
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
{
   udata->Ts[i]=Tstart[i];
   udata->dTs[i]=dT[i];
   udata->ts[i]=tstart[i];
}
for(i=0;i!=2*numRec;i++)
{
    udata->vkp[i]=vk[i];
}
```

The udata will be passed to ODE solver six times in a loop. At each time, I monitor the address of the dynamic arrays and its content with the code:

```
printf("udata->Ts: %p\n",udata->Ts);
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
printf("    Ts[%d]=%.5f ",i,udata->Ts[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("udata->dTs: %p\n",udata->dTs);
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
printf("    dTs[%d]=%.5f    ",i,udata->dTs[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("udata->ts: %p\n",udata->ts);
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
 printf("   ts[%d]=%.5f ",i,udata->ts[i]);
 printf("\n");
printf("udata->vkp: %p\n",udata->vkp);
for(i=0;i!=2*numRec;i++)
printf("    vkp[%d]=%.5f    ",i,udata->vkp[i]);
printf("\n");
```

The output at the first time:

```
 m = 0
udata->Ts: 0x62c430
Ts[0]=673.00000     Ts[1]=698.00000     Ts[2]=723.00000     Ts[3]=748.00000     Ts[4]=773.00000     Ts[5]=798.00000
udata->dTs: 0x638f30
dTs[0]=0.00000      dTs[1]=0.00000      dTs[2]=0.00000      dTs[3]=0.00000      dTs[4]=0.00000      dTs[5]=0.00000  
udata->ts: 0x638f70
ts[0]=316.09846     ts[1]=283.41932     ts[2]=253.00015     ts[3]=224.61435     ts[4]=198.06463     ts[5]=173.17842
udata->vkp: 0x62e150
vkp[0]=-4.22868     vkp[1]=-2.73312     vkp[2]=2.80980      vkp[3]=-1.65961     vkp[4]=27.23419     vkp[5]=25.96871vkp[6]=16.03558      vkp[7]=10.69316
```

As comparison, here is the sixth output,

```
udata->Ts: 0x62c430
Ts[0]=673.00000     Ts[1]=698.00000     Ts[2]=723.00000     Ts[3]=748.00000     Ts[4]=773.00000     Ts[5]=798.00000
udata->dTs: 0x638f30
dTs[0]=0.00000      dTs[1]=0.00000      dTs[2]=0.00000      dTs[3]=0.00000      dTs[4]=0.00000      dTs[5]=0.00000  
udata->ts: 0x638f70
ts[0]=316.09846     ts[1]=283.41932     ts[2]=253.00015     ts[3]=224.61435     ts[4]=198.06463     ts[5]=173.17842
udata->vkp: 0x62e150
vkp[0]=-4.22868     vkp[1]=-2.73312     vkp[2]=2.80980      vkp[3]=-1.65961     vkp[4]=27.23419     vkp[5]=25.96871vkp[6]=16.03558      vkp[7]=10.69316
```

After the loop, I just use the following syntax to release memory,

```
delete [] udata->Ts;
delete [] udata->dTs;
delete [] udata->ts;
delete [] udata->vkp;
udata=NULL;
```

It can be seen the pointer and the content pointer points to keeps the same. Nothing changed. So the problems other met is excluded. And this is the only place I use delete. 
ERROR information is as follows:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000062e150 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7ffff7286b96]
/home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso[0x405890]
/home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso[0x404b28]
/home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso[0x407482]
/home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso[0x409da5]
/home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso[0x40ba63]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff722976d]
/home/fenglei/mopso_oil_shale_cvode/mopso[0x401a09]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00429000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4209122                            {directory}/example
00628000-00629000 r--p 00028000 08:06 4209122                            {directory}/example
00629000-0062a000 rw-p 00029000 08:06 4209122                            {directory}/example
0062a000-0064b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff7208000-7ffff73bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 131963                     /lib/x86_64-    linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff73bd000-7ffff75bd000 ---p 001b5000 08:06 131963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff75bd000-7ffff75c1000 r--p 001b5000 08:06 131963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff75c1000-7ffff75c3000 rw-p 001b9000 08:06 131963                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff75c3000-7ffff75c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff75c8000-7ffff75dd000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 134855                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff75dd000-7ffff77dc000 ---p 00015000 08:06 134855                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff77dc000-7ffff77dd000 r--p 00014000 08:06 134855                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff77dd000-7ffff77de000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 134855                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff77de000-7ffff78d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 131976                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff78d9000-7ffff7ad8000 ---p 000fb000 08:06 131976                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7ad8000-7ffff7ad9000 r--p 000fa000 08:06 131976                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7ad9000-7ffff7ada000 rw-p 000fb000 08:06 131976                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7ada000-7ffff7bbc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5250632                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7bbc000-7ffff7dbb000 ---p 000e2000 08:06 5250632                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7dbb000-7ffff7dc3000 r--p 000e1000 08:06 5250632                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7dc3000-7ffff7dc5000 rw-p 000e9000 08:06 5250632                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7ffff7dc5000-7ffff7dda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7dda000-7ffff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7fdc000-7ffff7fe1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff6000-7ffff7ffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00022000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffffffdd000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff723e425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

This is the first time I post my questions here, although i got a lot of stuff from this website. I hope I made my problem clear.

Code:

```
/*
---------------------------------
*ODE problem solver definition
---------------------------------
*/

#include <stdio.h>
/* Header files with a description of contents used */

#include <cvode/cvode.h>             /* prototypes for CVODE fcts., consts. */
#include <nvector/nvector_serial.h>  /* serial N_Vector types, fcts., macros */
#include <cvode/cvode_dense.h>       /* prototype for CVDense */
#include <sundials/sundials_dense.h> /* definitions DlsMat DENSE_ELEM */
#include <sundials/sundials_types.h> /* definition of type realtype */
/* User-defined vector and matrix accessor macros: Ith, IJth */

/* These macros are defined in order to write code which exactly matches
   the mathematical problem description given above.

   Ith(v,i) references the ith component of the vector v, where i is in
   the range [1..NEQ] and NEQ is defined below. The Ith macro is defined
   using the N_VIth macro in nvector.h. N_VIth numbers the components of
   a vector starting from 0.

   IJth(A,i,j) references the (i,j)th element of the dense matrix A, where
   i and j are in the range [1..NEQ]. The IJth macro is defined using the
   DENSE_ELEM macro in dense.h. DENSE_ELEM numbers rows and columns of a
   dense matrix starting from 0. */

#define Ith(v,i)    NV_Ith_S(v,i-1)       /* Ith numbers components 1..NEQ */
#define IJth(A,i,j) DENSE_ELEM(A,i-1,j-1) /* IJth numbers rows,cols 1..NEQ */

/* Problem Constants */
#define RTOL  RCONST(1.0e-4)   /* scalar relative tolerance            */
#define ATOL1 RCONST(1.0e-8)   /* vector absolute tolerance components */
#define ATOL2 RCONST(1.0e-8)
#define ATOL3 RCONST(1.0e-8)
#define ATOL4 RCONST(1.0e-8)
#define Y(i) yt[i-1]
#define K(i) kt[i-1]

 typedef struct {
  unsigned int exp_ID, nExp,nRec, nComp;
  realtype *Ts;
  realtype *dTs;
  realtype *ts;
  realtype *vkp;
  realtype Tr;
} User;
typedef User *UserData;
/* Functions Called by the Solver */
static int f(realtype t, N_Vector y, N_Vector ydot, void *user_data);
static int Jac(long int N, realtype t,
           N_Vector y, N_Vector fy, DlsMat J, void *user_data,
           N_Vector tmp1, N_Vector tmp2, N_Vector tmp3);
/* Private function to check function return values */

static int check_flag(void *flagvalue, const char *funcname, int opt);

int Reaction::cvodedensewrapper()
{
  int i=0,j=0,k=0,m=0,numt;
  realtype reltol,t,tout,ts;
  N_Vector y, abstol;
  void *cvode_mem;
  int iout, flag;
  User data;
  UserData udata=& data;
  /*Allocation and initialization*/
  udata->Ts=new realtype[numExp];
  udata->dTs=new realtype[numExp];
  udata->ts=new realtype[numExp];
  udata->vkp=new realtype[2*numRec];
  udata->nExp=numExp;
  udata->nRec=numRec;
  udata->nComp=numComp;
  udata->Tr=Tref;

  for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
  {
    udata->Ts[i]=Tstart[i];
    udata->dTs[i]=dT[i];
    udata->ts[i]=tstart[i];
  }
   for(i=0;i!=2*numRec;i++)
  {
    udata->vkp[i]=vk[i];
  }
  /*for debugging*/
  printf("udata->Ts: %p\n",udata->Ts);
  for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
    printf("    Ts[%d]=%.5f ",i,udata->Ts[i]);
   printf("\n");
   printf("udata->dTs: %p\n",udata->dTs);
   for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
    printf("    dTs[%d]=%.5f    ",i,udata->dTs[i]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("udata->ts: %p\n",udata->ts);
  for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
    printf("    ts[%d]=%.5f ",i,udata->ts[i]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("udata->vkp: %p\n",udata->vkp);
  for(i=0;i!=2*numRec;i++)
    printf("    vkp[%d]=%.5f    ",i,udata->vkp[i]);
  printf("\n");
/*debugging end*/
  y = abstol = NULL;
  cvode_mem = NULL;
 /* Create serial vector of length numRec for I.C. and abstol */
  y = N_VNew_Serial(numComp);
  if (check_flag((void *)y, "N_VNew_Serial", 0)) return(1);
  abstol = N_VNew_Serial(numComp); 
  if (check_flag((void *)abstol, "N_VNew_Serial", 0)) return(1);

  /* Initialize y */
  for(i=0;i!=numComp;i++)
  {
    //Ith(y,i)=Yinitial[0][i-1];
     NV_Ith_S(y,i)=Yinitial[0][i];
  }
 /*Initialize tstart*/
  ts=tstart[0];
  /* Set the scalar relative tolerance */
  reltol = RTOL;
  /* Set the vector absolute tolerance */
    Ith(abstol,1)=ATOL1;
    Ith(abstol,2)=ATOL2;
    Ith(abstol,3)=ATOL3;
    Ith(abstol,4)=ATOL3;
  /* Call CVodeCreate to create the solver memory and specify the 
   * Backward Differentiation Formula and the use of a Newton iteration */
  cvode_mem = CVodeCreate(CV_BDF, CV_NEWTON);
  if (check_flag((void *)cvode_mem, "CVodeCreate", 0)) return(1);
  /* Set the pointer to user-defined data*/
  flag=CVodeSetUserData(cvode_mem,udata);
  if(check_flag((void *) cvode_mem,"CVodeCreate",0)) return(1);

  /* Call CVodeInit to initialize the integrator memory and specify the
   * user's right hand side function in y'=f(t,y), the inital time T0, and
   * the initial dependent variable vector y. */
  flag = CVodeInit(cvode_mem, f, ts, y);
  if (check_flag(&flag, "CVodeInit", 1)) return(1);

  /* Call CVodeSVtolerances to specify the scalar relative tolerance
   * and vector absolute tolerances */
  flag = CVodeSVtolerances(cvode_mem, reltol, abstol);
  if (check_flag(&flag, "CVodeSVtolerances", 1)) return(1);

  /* Call CVDense to specify the CVDENSE dense linear solver */
  flag = CVDense(cvode_mem, numComp);
  if (check_flag(&flag, "CVDense", 1)) return(1);

  /* Set the Jacobian routine to Jac (user-supplied) */
  flag = CVDlsSetDenseJacFn(cvode_mem, Jac);
  if (check_flag(&flag, "CVDlsSetDenseJacFn", 1)) return(1);

  /* In loop, call CVode, print results, and test for error.
   Break out of loop when NOUT preset output times have been reached.  */
 for (m=0;m!=numExp;m++) {
        numt=(int)(tend[m]-tstart[m])/dtsave[m]+1;
    udata->exp_ID=m;
    Yt[m].tvector[0]=tstart[m];
    Yt[m].Tvector[0]=Tstart[m];
    for(i=0;i!=numComp;i++)
    {
       Yt[m].resp[i][0]=Yinitial[m][i];
    }
    for(i=0;i!=numComp;i++)
   {
      //Ith(y,i)=Yinitial[m][i-1];
      NV_Ith_S(y,i)=Yinitial[m][i];
   }
  ts=tstart[m];
  flag = CVodeReInit(cvode_mem,ts, y);
  iout = 0;  
  tout = tstart[m]+dtsave[m];
  while(1) {
    flag = CVode(cvode_mem, tout, y, &t, CV_NORMAL);
    if (check_flag(&flag, "CVodeInit", 1)) return(1);
    if (flag == CV_SUCCESS) {
      iout++;
      tout=t+dtsave[m];
    }
    Yt[m].tvector[iout]=t;
    Yt[m].Tvector[iout]=Tstart[m]+(Yt[m].tvector[iout]-Yt[m].tvector[0])*dT[m];
    for(i=0;i!=numComp;i++)
    {
         //Yt[m].resp[i-1][iout]=Ith(y,i);
            Yt[m].resp[i][iout]=NV_Ith_S(y,i);
    }
    if (iout == numt) break;
  }
/*for debugging*/
printf("udata->Ts: %p\n",udata->Ts);
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
printf("    Ts[%d]=%.5f ",i,udata->Ts[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("udata->dTs: %p\n",udata->dTs);
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
 printf("   dTs[%d]=%.5f    ",i,udata->dTs[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("udata->ts: %p\n",udata->ts);
for(i=0;i!=numExp;i++)
 printf("   ts[%d]=%.5f ",i,udata->ts[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("udata->vkp: %p\n",udata->vkp);
for(i=0;i!=2*numRec;i++)
    printf("    vkp[%d]=%.5f    ",i,udata->vkp[i]);
printf("\n");
/*debugging end*/

}
  /*Free userdata*/
  delete [] udata->Ts;
  delete [] udata->dTs;
  delete [] udata->ts;
  delete [] udata->vkp;
  udata=NULL;
  /*Free ODE solver array*/
  N_VDestroy_Serial(y);
  N_VDestroy_Serial(abstol);
  /* Free integrator memory */
  CVodeFree(&cvode_mem);
  return(0);

}

/*
 *-------------------------------
 * Functions called by the solver
 *-------------------------------
 */

/*
 * f routine. Compute function f(t,y). 
*/


/*
 * Jacobian routine. Compute J(t,y) = df/dy. *
 */
```

Functions with CV initils are from shared libraries.

Comment: What is `realtype` and why do those members need to be pointers? If I had to guess, I'd say you're violating the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) leading to double deletion.

Comment: realtype is just name for double type, I payed attention to double deletion. But I only have one place to use delete. And I can print the pointer address and its content just before the delete syntax as above. It should not be ble dethe douletion problem.

Comment: If they are plain doubles then why do you need those members to be `double *` instead of just `vector<double>`? If they were the latter, you wouldn't have to `new[]` and `delete[]`, and your problem would most likely disappear. If you insist on using raw pointers and managing memory yourself, then make `User` Rule of Three compliant.

Comment: @Albert Pointers and the values they point at are not modified when memory is freed. You can't look at them to see if they've been deleted. As the message says, there could also be corruption. Print the pointers immediately after allocation to rule that out.

Comment: It seems you haven't grasped C++ in terms of pointers and addresses. Why are you doing this: `User data;UserData udata=&data;`?? It gives the impression that you're using that pointer out-of-scope of `User data`, and doing that is undefined behavior. Why not post a complete main() program, and not snippets so that we can see in full view the scope of these variables, how you're passing that struct, etc.  BTW, what you wrote is basically 'C' code, not C++.

Comment: @Praetorian, I need to pass variables to c code. I guess I can't call c functions with vector.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Thanks. I just tried. The pointers didn't change. I guess it's not the corruption of pointers.

Comment: @Albert - You can use vectors. A pointer to the first element of a vector is your `double*`. A `vector` is nothing more than a wrapper for `new[]` and `delete[]`, but with intelligence and features built into it.

Comment: @Albert At least that's ruled out, then. I have a feeling that the problem lies in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I always worry about using vector when calling c functions. I will try that. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Albert - `std::vector<double> dv;  dv.resize(100,0); foo(&dv[0]);`  If `foo` is a function that takes a `double *`, the code is the same as doing that new[]/delete[] stuff you're doing now to create a dynamic array.  A vector is `safer`, `easier to use`, `compatible with functions that takes pointers to a buffer`  has `no memory leaks`, an `cleans up when it goes out of scope`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I just posted source code above. PaulMcKenzie gives some good suggestions. I may modify the code following these suggestions. But if you can find the errs, that will help me understand where the problems are. Thank you, all guys

Comment: Does the C function do any reallocation of memory?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly in the code you *didn't* show.

According to [documentation](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/cv_guide/node5.html) for `CVodeSetUserData`, it simply passes `UserData` through to the function that the solver will eventually invoke (`f` in this case).

In any case, *the* tool that will point you straight at your bug is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org). Just run your program under it, and it will tell you exactly how you are corrupting your heap.